# Angular unit testing of then() in service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a service as follows:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('mymodule')
  .factory('myservice', ['$http', ($http) ->
    return {
      get: ->
        return $http.get('/abc/details')
          .then (response) ->
            return response.data
    }
  ])
```

and my unit test is as follows:

```
describe 'Testing myservice', ->

  _myservice_ = null
  httpBackend = null

  beforeEach module 'mymodule'

  beforeEach inject (myservice, $httpBackend) ->
    _myservice_ = myservice
    httpBackend = $httpBackend


  describe 'When get()', ->
    it "GET request is sent to /abc/details", ->
      httpBackend.whenGET("/abc/details").respond
        data:
          name: 'company name',
          addressee: 'Mary Jane'

      returnedPromise =_myservice_.get()

      result = returnedPromise.then (response) ->
        result = response.data

      httpBackend.flush()
      expect(result).toEqual({name: 'company name', addressee: 'Mary Jane'})
```

In my service, the response is actually being processed in the `then()` (i.e. return only `response.data`). My question is, how do I (unit) test that `myservice.get()` returns me `response.data` instead of `response`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your service doesn't return a promise of HTTP response, but a promise of data, the test should be

```
returnedPromise.then (data) ->
     result = data

httpBackend.flush()

expect(result).toEqual({name: 'company name', addressee: 'Mary Jane'})
```

I also assume the real REST service doesn't actually return an object containing a single data field. So the mocking should look like

```
httpBackend.whenGET("/abc/details").respond
    {
       name: 'company name',
       addressee: 'Mary Jane'
    }
```

(Sorry if it isn't valid coffeescript. I use JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I get the following error  ```Expected { data : { name : 'company name', addressee : 'Mary Jane' } } to equal { name : 'company name', addressee : 'Mary Jane' }.``` with the recommended changes.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's because your mock httpBackend responds with an object containing a single `data` field, which I suppose is not really what the real http service returns.